# Create a horizontal PageView with ListViews of different heights

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create design like in Instagram profile page. There they have 2 ListViews, one of which is your regular photos and the second is the photos you've been tagged in.

These 2 ListViews may have different heights, but switching between them is seamless. What I did is a PageView wrapped in container with variable height, and when I'm switching from longer ListView to shorter one, cutting-like animation occurs. How to accomplish normal switching between them?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code to get a better understanding

Comment: @AyushBherwani, I updated the post with the gif

Comment: Maybe you can include a variable to handle the dimensions of the list and when you switch the variable value change too

Comment: @HaironChaviano, can you please explain it?

Comment: do you want to swipe between two listviews and the listviews size don't change at all?

Comment: @HaironChaviano, Well yes but actually no... Now I think that it's probably impossible to make something like this without some tricky technique. Would be glad if someone would tell me his implementation though

Comment: Well @ZhangirSiranov I don't know if my solution is the best or even if is capable of solving your problem but I think you can declare a variable in the view with the size of the initial listview and when you switch to another listview the value change, if you want share your code to take a look